# How to create a randomised field survey roster in R?

Tags: r, random, sampling

I would like to create a random field survey roster in R.

I have a team of 5 people surveying every day for 7 days. I need to split 4 people into 2 teams, with 1 person off each day. Each team visits 1 out of 2 plots every day. I want to ensure that each plot is visited as equally as possible by all people over the 7 day survey period.

My expected outcome is to have something like the following table but with the people randomised for each day, equally distributed across plots (plotA, plotB, off) for the seven days.

| plot | day1 | day2 | day3 | day4 | day5 | day6 | day7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| plotA | Peter | Peter | Peter | Peter | Peter | Peter | Peter |
| plotA | Maria | Maria | Maria | Maria | Maria | Maria | Maria |
| plotB | Brian | Brian | Brian | Brian | Brian | Brian | Brian |
| plotB | Steph | Steph | Steph | Steph | Steph | Steph | Steph |
| off | Sharon | Sharon | Sharon | Sharon | Sharon | Sharon | Sharon |

I've tried using the sample() function but cannot get it to do what I want.

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly: do you want a truly random assignment of inspectors (meaning that, by chance, Peter might show up three days in a row on plot A)? Or do you want an equal distribution of assignments across team members, in which case you could simply rotate people - unless there's plausible reason to expect individual observation bias with weekday, which might be true for Monday mornings ;-)

Comment: Yes to an equal distribution of assignments across team members. However, each plot appears twice and therefore Peter shouldn't be in row 1 for plotA or row 2 for plotA three times in a row. Luckily every day is structured the same in the field so that the weekday shouldn't have any effect, most of the time we don't really know what day of the week it actually is.